# Summing list elements based on a list of indices

Tags: python, list

How could I get to result and abResult? Please guide me through, I really appreciate it!

```
x=[1,2]      

y=[3,4,5]

result= [3,9]   <===  the sum of result determine by x
```

=============OR==========

```
a=[1,3,2]

b= [4,2,3,4,5,10]

abResult= [4,9,15]
```

Comment: Should we have any idea how you got from the first 2 lists to the results? or just guess?

Comment: so basically, a[0]=1 then you sum(b[1]) OR a[1]=3 then you sum(2,3,4) of b, hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a=[1,3,2]

b= [4,2,3,4,5,10]

res=[]

for i in a:
    res.append(sum(b[:i]))
    b=b[i:]
```

res stores your result

Answer (score -1):

It's may be work fine.

```
def isValid(counter, array): # valid if sum of counter equals array length
    return sum(counter) == len(array)

def calc(counter, array):
    if not isValid(counter, array):
        return []
    flag = 0
    for x in counter:
        yield sum(array[flag:flag+x]) # sum between (flag ~ flag+x)
        flag += x                     # add x to flag for next flag
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but the use of `list` as an argument is very bad practice since `list` is a type name / built in function. Also, I fail to understand how this answer solves the problem, since you didn't explain

Comment: oh, I see, I'll fix answer and add some explain